# Rails server won't start after I did a bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

After I did a `bundle update`, I get this error when i try to run rails s:

(The only thing I added was a `bcrypt-ruby` gem, but I dont think that has anything to with this...)

```
/Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `less' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fc33b079468> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.6/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:15:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/fettass/Documents/RailsApps/epyhrepus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fettass/Documents/RailsApps/epyhrepus/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /Users/fettass/Documents/RailsApps/epyhrepus/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/fettass/Documents/RailsApps/epyhrepus/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/fettass/Documents/RailsApps/epyhrepus/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/fettass/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should never do a `bundle update` unless you *really* want to update every single Gem in your Gemfile. When you add a new Gem, do a `bundle install`. If you want to update a Gem that is already installed, do a `bundle update gemname`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was wondering what the difference was :) (Did I do any damage by using `update` and not `install` - and why sould I not use `update`?)

Comment: Say you have Rails in your Gemfile, without the version being specified. If you bundled at Rails 3.2, and Rails 4 comes out, by doing `bundle update` you will end up at Rails 4, quite possibly breaking your app in the process. `bundle update` can cause issues simply by over-aggressively updating all your gems. You pretty much would never want to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add the less-rails gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem "less-rails", "~> 2.2.6"
```

Comment: YES! Thanks that worked (I also had to install the `therubyracer` gem). But I have used less all the time, why does it complain now, and not earlier? Also - what is the difference between the commands `bundle`, `bundle install` and `bundle update`?

Comment: If you're using the asset-pipeline and have the gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", you are [required to also use "less-rails"](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#installing-gem) with it. bundle and bundle install are the same command. Here's a [description of the differences between bundle install and bundle update](http://viget.com/extend/bundler-best-practices).